# Flexbox grid - justify: space-around and aligning last items left

Tags: html, css, alignment, flexbox

Trying to set-up my `flexbox` grid as simply as possible.

I want the `flex-item` to be `justify: space-around` at all times.

However, once it is time for a `flex-item` to wrap to the next line, it should '*float left*' so it can continue to align to the rest of the elements above.

Can't seem to get the right combination of `flexbox` properties to do this:

```css
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item{
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em;
}

.flex-item:after{
  content:'';
  flex-grow: 1000000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Pretty standard layout behavior for a grid of products right?

Anyone got an idea how I can achieve this?
 Maybe I am 'missing something' with how `flexbox` is meant to be used, but I sadly had to revert to my old `float`s and `clear`s to get what I wanted for this layout.

Comment: You can't do that (in general). Each line is independent. Flexbox has no grid notion.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38000723/3597276

Comment: Why don't you use space-between? I think it works. https://jsfiddle.net/fdbgef7d/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to justify the content. use `margin` instead.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*optional*/
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 980px
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Update

> I want the flex-items to be able to distribute neatly within the
>   `flex-container`, no matter how wide it is. However, if the the
>   `flex-container` gets below a `width` that can contain the `flex-items` at
>   the minimum spacing allowed = the `margin: 1em` of each `flex-item`, they
>   should wrap, floating left and aligning to the flexible grid

You can use the hack provided **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38000860/3448527)** by @Michael_B , using `::after`
won't work 100%, but close to that.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between
}
.flex-container::after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  width: 232px
  /* width + 2x(margin: 1em) */
}
.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

### Update #2

> Yes saw that one thanks @dippas. Unfortunately this work-around
>   requires manually setting CSS or writing javascript - and I definitely
>   want a pure CSS solution. The flex-items will be generated
>   dynamically, so I can't know what number there are, which is necessary
>   for Michael_B's solution

Then forget `flexbox` because it can't do what you want, just use `inline-block`

```css
.flex-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response - but this is lacking the functionality of a (a) flexible container, where you do not have a manually set the width with media queries and (b) the flex-items are not automatically spacing horizontally - they are floating left in all rows, without retaining the flexible spacing. I perhaps should have specified that in my question, though it is in my example.

Comment: so what you want exactly?  a full screen with divs or you want just a "small" container with the child divs inside? Hard to understand, that's why I stated in a comment that the width was optional

Comment: Yes I want the flex-items to be able to distribute neatly within the flex-container, no matter how wide it is. However, if the the flex-container gets below a width that can contain the flex-items at the minimum spacing allowed  = the margin: 1em of each flex-item, they should wrap, floating left and aligning to the flexible grid. I hope that is clear.

Comment: Yes saw that one thanks @dippas. Unfortunately this work-around requires manually setting CSS or writing javascript - and I definitely want a pure CSS solution. The flex-items will be generated dynamically, so I can't know what number there are, which is necessary for Michael_B's solution. Still seems I'll have to go back to floats/ clears and using child-elements for this functionality.

Comment: what about `inline-block` option? see updated answer, otherwise, media queries, forget floats/clears

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116325/discussion-between-spacewindow-and-dippas).